# Not able to uninstall Appium 2.0.0-beta.46 on mac Monterey

Tags: npm, appium, npm-install, beta

I used npm to install **appium 2.0.0-beta.46.**
After that I installed appium 1.22, but the appium -v still shows **2.0.0-beta.46.**

So I tried various options

- npm uninstall -g appium@2.0.0-beta.46
- sudo npm uninstall -g appium@2.0.0-beta.46
- sudo npm uninstall -g appium@beta
- sudo npm uninstall -g appium@next
  Plus
- npm cache clean --force
  But still, I am getting
  **$ appium -v
  2.0.0-beta.46**

When I did
**$which appium,** I get
*/usr/local/bin/appium*

I rebooted the system twice, but no use.
What is the best way to do the uninstall the 2.0.0-beta.46 and go back to 1.22 ?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: BTW, when I ran
npm -g list, I get the below list

/Users/<userID>/.nvm/versions/node/v19.0.0/lib
├── appium@1.22.3
├── corepack@0.14.2
└── npm@8.19.2

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps also uninstall appium 1.22, hoping all is cleaned up after that.

```
npm uninstall -g appium
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I am unable to uninstall all the fragments of Appium 2.0, 1.22, node etc., I took the risk of installing the trialware PowerMyMac tool, and could able to clean all the software. I know it is not a solid solution and I won't suggest to others, but I was desperate and it did worked.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve issue, I deleted appium folder from root and installed latest appium version using npm install -g appium@version . Eg: npm install -g appium@2.0.0-beta.55

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the appium folder as specified under `which appium`, ie

```
% which appium
/usr/local/bin/appium
% rm -rf /usr/local/bin/appium
```

After that I was able to successfully uninstall and reinstall latest appium:

```
% npm uninstall -g appium
up to date in 333ms
% npm install -g appium@latest

added 449 packages in 24s

57 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details
% appium -v
2.5.1
```